# Basic method chaining with DOM elements

Tags: javascript

I have been trying to learn how to chain methods in vanilla JS. Following simple tutorials I can `add()`, `subtract()` etc. However, going solo and trying to chain DOM elements, I am struggling with.

In the following snippet nothing is outputted, which I believe is due to `this.textContent` line. How do I get the `getId` bit?

```js
'use strict'
let chain = {
    getId(id) {
        document.getElementById(id);
        return this;
    },
    text(content) {
        this.textContent = content;
        return this;
    }
}
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
    let dummy = chain.getId('dummy').text('works');
})
```

```html
<div id='dummy'></div>
```

Comment: `this` in the context of your Object method belongs to the Object, not your Element, which is a different Object. `return this;` is what allows the chaining of other methods to other Object methods.

Comment: @StackSlave thank you; for augmenting my working knowledge. It is most appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already explained in [a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62379537/basic-method-chaining-with-dom-elements#comment110324103_62379537) `this` is not the selected element. With minimal refactoring in your code what you can do is adding a new `element` property to your object, setting it in `getId` and using that element in `text`. For instance:

```js
'use strict'
let chain = {
  element: null,
  getId(id) {
    this.element = document.getElementById(id);
    return this
  },
  text(content) {
    this.element.textContent = content;
    return this;
  }
}
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
  let dummy = chain.getId('dummy').text('works');
})
```

```html
<div id='dummy'></div>
```